# Adding theme support for app using listpreference

Tags: android

I am trying to add theme support to app. It is working, but I want user to choose between themes. The problem is, I cannot do that I tried so many things. I am using ListPreference to define a list of arrays for user to choose. I cannot link those listpreference entry values with util. 
If I edit "0" in Util with any number, themes work but it doesnt work when I change those entry values (from list in phone)IDK why.
Below is the code

**Settings.java**

```
 public class Settings extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Util.setAppTheme(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        PrefsFragment mPrefsFragment = new PrefsFragment();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, mPrefsFragment);
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();


    }

    public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
        }

    }
```

**Util.java**

```
public class Util extends Activity {

public static void setAppTheme(Activity a) {

SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(a);
int mTheme = Integer.parseInt(sp.getString("theme", "0"));
if(mTheme==0)
{

    a.setTheme(R.style.Dark);
}
if(mTheme==1)
{
    a.setTheme(R.style.Light);
}
if(mTheme==2)
{
    a.setTheme(R.style.LimeLight);
}
if(mTheme==3)
{
    a.setTheme(R.style.MojoLight);
}
if(mTheme==4)
{
    a.setTheme(R.style.SanMarinoLight);
}
if(mTheme==5)
{
    a.setTheme(R.style.LimeDark);
}
if(mTheme==6)
{
    a.setTheme(R.style.MojoDark);
}
if(mTheme==7)
{
    a.setTheme(R.style.SanMarinoDark);
}

}
}
```

**preferences.xml**

```
<PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/preference_category2_title">
        <ListPreference android:key="list2_preference"
            android:title="@string/list2_title"
            android:summary="@string/list2_summary"
            android:entries="@array/list2_preferences"
            android:entryValues="@array/list2_preferences_values"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/list2_dialog_title"/>
        <SwitchPreference android:key="switch1_preference"
            android:title="@string/switch1_title"
            android:switchTextOff="@string/switch1_textoff"
            android:switchTextOn="@string/switch1_texton"
            />
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Dark -->
<style name="Dark" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/activity_background_dark</item>
</style>

<!-- Light -->
<style name="Light" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar_Light</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/activity_background_light</item>

</style>
```

**arrays.xml**

```
<resources>

<string-array name="list2_preferences">
    <item>Dark</item>
    <item>Light</item>
    <item>Light Lime</item>
    <item>Light Mojo</item>
    <item>Light San Marino</item>
    <item>Dark Lime</item>
    <item>Dark Mojo</item>
    <item>Dark San Marino</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="list2_preferences_values">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>

</string-array>
```

I will be thankful if anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

What is your on code for the onItemSelected method of your list?

Also you can't change the theme of an activity after you've initialized it's layout.
In my current application I also allow the user to change the theme. To achieve this I simply start the activity again passing an argument (the selected theme) and finish the current one.
In the activity `onCreate()` I then check the argument. If it's -1 (activity first time start) I get the default theme.

```
private static final String INTENT_EXTRA = "theme";
private boolean onCreate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    onCreate = true;

    themeId = getIntent().getIntExtra(INTENT_EXTRA, -1);
    if (themeId == -1) {
        themeId = SharedPreferencesManagment
                .getApplicationThemeResourceId(SharedPreferencesManagment
                        .getIntApplicationTheme(this));
    } else {
        themeId = SharedPreferencesManagment
                .getApplicationThemeResourceId(themeId);
    }
    setTheme(themeId);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_options_theme);

    initSpinner();
 }
```

In the list's `onItemSelected()` method I call something like:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (!onCreate) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OptionsThemeActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA, getSelectedTheme());
        startActivity(intent);

        finish();
    }
    onCreate = false;
}
```

Also note the onCreate-boolean as the `onItemSelected()`-method is also called when the activity inits the spinner.
(Was the simpliest workaround to prevent a infinte loop)

ALSO:
Why is Util a Activity? If the code you've posted is everything you do with Util you don't need to extend Activity as you pass the context.